# Asyncronous storage Issue react native

Tags: php, mysql, react-native, api, asynchronous

I am implementing login/signup in React Native uses Asynchronous storage. Here, when I login/signup successfully. And navigating to another page and getting the information from the Async storage stored in the previous session After login, same user_id using into this page, but not getting user_id using Async storage. Here the snippet.

```
 async data() {
    this.setState({loading:true});
    let url = API.GAME;
    cosnole.log(url);
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    cosnole.log(url);
    let user = JSON.parse(value);
    let user_id = user.id;
    cosnole.log(user_id);
    let data = {
        user_id:user_id,
    };
    cosnole.log(data);
```

The problem is it that when I use this method and console the function, I get an error in response saying ['user_id: undefined']. Sometime login with 'A' id and Async return previous login id 'B'.

i am posting user data after signup here the snippet

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", "game").then(response=>{
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('user_id',this.props.navigation.state.params.user_id).then(async (res)=>{
                        await AsyncStorage.setItem('firstLogin',"true");

                        let url = API.getprofile;
                        let data = {
                            user_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.user_id,
                        };
                        try{
                            let response = await fetch(
                                url,
                                {
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                                }
                            );
                            let responseJson = await response.json();
                            if (responseJson.status === 1) {
                                this.state.user_data = responseJson.user;
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(responseJson.user)).then((result)=>{
                                    this.Show_Custom_Alert(false);
                                    this.props.navigation.navigate('app');
```

What should i do?
Thanks

Comment: how u save the data post more code

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz sure